# Asymptote giving error when running from the cmd

Tags: miktex, asymptote

Recently I have installed asymptote in order to try to create some 3d graphics, I have been trying to load a simple hello world program from the cmd and it gives me the error:

```
pic.addBox(position,position,min(f),max(f));
\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX/asymptote/plain_Label.asy: 321.15: runtime:
```

I have the latest version of ghostscript installed but for some reason I have not been able to get asymptote to work. Any help for this would be appreaciated greatly.

Comment: [I have the same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTwTh.jpg). Updated Ghostscript 9.54 to Ghostscript 10.0.0 for Windows (64 bit). Didn't help. Strange, but double click works.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Asymptote\asy.bat" %1
This works!

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript 9.54 is broken; use [Ghostscript 9.53](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/tag/gs9533) instead.

Also uninstall the old version of Asymptote you are using and [install the latest version of Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) (2.70).

Comment: I tried that and it didnt make a difference. the error is still the same

Comment: +1: Maybe combine both answers into one.